# Elasticsearch - how to search for part of word across all indices and documents

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to make a search that works like this:

- when I enter "Desc" for example, I want to get everything that contains "Desc", and not to be case sensitive. I don't want to include index name, or document, I want it to search across everything.

I tried this but it doesn't work very well.

```html
GET /_search 
{
  "query": 
      { "query_string": 
          { 
            "query": "Test*" 
          } 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using wild card search. Make sure the field you are searching is `text` field.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "*desc*"
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use all index you can query like this

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index1,index2/_search
```

PS: Performance wise this is a bad idea since this searches all fields in index. Alternatively you can use use `default_field` in the query string and specidy the field.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that too. And it is correct way, it is just that I had more than 10 results, and default value of size is 10. I had to add "size": 100 (or whatever number is suitable).

Answer (score 2):

From the latest docs any of these techniques will get you the job done

```
  GET /_search
    {
      "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "*desc*"
        }
      }
    }

    **OR**

    GET /_all/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "*desc*"
        }
      }
    }

    **OR** 

    GET /*/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "*desc*"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multiple-indices.html